# Is there a closed-form way to make a matrix hollow?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ a matrix with entries $a_{ij} \ge 0$ and $\mathrm{det}(A)\neq 0$. I am interested in finding a closed matrix form operation such that $A$ becomes hollow.

> In other words, if I want to obtain
>   $$
> \tilde{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}\quad\text{such that}\quad \tilde{a}_{ij}=a_{ij}\;\forall (i\neq j)\quad\text{and}\quad\tilde{a}_{ii}=0
> $$
>   with constant matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that
>   $$
> \tilde A=PAQ
> $$
>   is it possible?

I tried a simple example, when $N=2$ and with brute force I found an interesting correlation with a transformation matrix $Q$ (here $P=I$), but I do not know how (and if) it is generalizable to $N>2$:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\tilde{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & b\\
c & 0
\end{pmatrix}=PAQ=IAQ=AQ=A\cdot\frac{1}{\det{A}}\begin{pmatrix}
-bc & bd\\
ac & -bc
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**EDIT**
From the comments, it has been pointed out that what I seek is not possible, meaning $P$ and $Q$ do not exist. Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you looking for a formula/function that accepts a matrix and returns the same matrix but with zeros on the main diagonal?

Comment: @GuySa Yes, exactly

Comment: To zero out the diagonal of $A$ means to subtracting $A$ by $\sum_{i=1}^nE_{ii}AE_{ii}$. As $I_{n^2}-\sum_{i=1}^n(E_{ii}\otimes E_{ii})$ is not a Kronecker product, you cannot obtain the zeroed out $A$ by a matrix product of the form $PAQ$ using constant matrices $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: @user1551 Your comment is interesting, but not very clear, could you elaborate in the form of an answer?

Comment: @AndreaL.: If $n>1$ and the matrix $A$ consists of ones everywhere, i.e. $a_{ij}=1$ for all $i,j$, such $P$ and $Q$ cannot exist, because $\operatorname{rank}(PAQ)\leq 1$ (since $\operatorname{rank}(A)=1$) whereas $\operatorname{rank}(\widetilde{A})>1$.

Comment: @DejanGovc I see, that's neat... I wonder if this argument can work on full rank matrices. For instance, can I infer that if $\mathrm{rank}(A)=k<N$, then my above procedure cannot work because $\mathrm{rank}(\tilde A)>k$? This seems to raise the constraint on $A$ that it must be only full rank in order for the multiplication to work...

Comment: If @user1551 does not post an answer within the bounty period, I will do so after the bounty has expired. However, Andrea, you may be able to figure it out yourself after reading Wikipedia's page on [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), paying special attention to the section on compatibility with Kronecker products.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, I had not put much attention to this question (due to thesis writing and such). I will definetly try to figure it out before the bounty expires.

Comment: Good luck for your thesis!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question, you would like to have $$P\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}Q=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
This is not possible, since the left side has determinant $0$, and the right side has determinant $-1$.

With $N>2$, the story is the same using a matrix of all $1$s, which we can denote $\mathbf{1}$. In that case, you want $$P\mathbf{1}Q=\mathbf{1}-I$$ The left side has determinant $0$. As for the right side, note that $$(\mathbf{1}-I)\left(\frac{1}{N-1}\mathbf{1}-I\right)=\frac{N}{N-1}\mathbf{1}-\mathbf{1}-\frac{1}{N-1}\mathbf{1}+I=I$$ so the right side is invertible, and has nonzero determinant.

---

The question now stipulates that $\det A$ is nonzero. Consider a sequence $\{A_n\}$ of invertible matrices converging to $\mathbf{1}$. Then assuming such $P,Q$ exist:
$$
\begin{align}
PA_nQ&=A_n-\operatorname{diag}(A_n)\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(PA_nQ\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(A_n-\operatorname{diag}(A_n)\right)\\
P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n\right)Q&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(A_n\right)-\operatorname{diag}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(A_n\right)\right)\\
P\mathbf{1}Q&=\mathbf{1}-I
\end{align}
$$
which we have shown is impossible. So unless you further refine "in general" to exclude invertible matrices converging to $\mathbf{1}$, this can't be done.

Perhaps you are interested in a different question than what is posted:

> For *which* matrices $A$ does there exist matrices $P,Q$ such that $PAQ=A-\operatorname{diag}{A}$?"

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex, it is however an answer for a very special case, for which $a_{ij}=1\;\forall (i,j)$. My question regards the possibility to hollowify a matrix in the general case, as stated in my first equation

Comment: @AndreaL. Right. But you hope to have some way to do it in general, and if this demonstrates it cannot be done in one case, then it cannot be done "in general".

Comment: What you say is true, but I beg to differ. In this context, the example you showed works for a $\mathrm{det}= 0$ matrix, which is an extremely special case! I do not see from your proof how it implies that the above procedure cannot work for $\mathrm{det}\neq 0$ matrices. I admit that my question was unclear about the determinant, I will modify it promptly, and I am sorry about the confusion

Comment: You lost me at "is true, but I beg to differ". But I've extended the answer to explain why it still doesn't work.